# Append Circles to 1 Line in a D3 Multi-Line chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a multi-line chart representing 8 different series of values, for a given date:
http://bl.ocks.org/eoiny/8548406

I have managed to filter out **series1** and append circles for each data-point for **series1** only, using:

```
var filtered = city
      .filter(function(d){
          return d.name == "series1"
      })

      filtered           
            .selectAll('circle')
            .data(
              function(d){return d.values}                
                  )
            .enter().append('circle')
            .attr({
              cx: function(d,i){
                return x(d.date)
              },
              cy: function(d,i){
                return y(d.pindex)
              },
              r:  5
            })
```

However I am trying to append 4 circles to my series1 line, one for each of the following values only:

1. min value in series1,
2. max value in series1,
3. 1st value in series1,
4. last value in series1.

I approached this problem by looking at the "filtered" array and I tried using something like this to catch the min & max values to start with:

```
.attr("visibility", function(d) {
     if (d.pindex == d3.max(filtered, function(d) { return d.pindex; })) {return "visible"}
     if (d.pindex == d3.min(filtered, function(d) { return d.pindex; })) {return "visible"}
     else    { return "hidden" }  
                 ;})
```

But I'm somehow getting muddled up by the fact that the data I need is in an object within the filtered array. I know that filtered should look like this:

```
[{
name: "series1",
  values: [{date: "2005-01-01",
               pindex: "100"},
              {date: "2005-02-01"
              pindex: "100.4"}, ...etc for all data points i.e. dates
             ]
    }]
```

So I tried something like this:

```
d.pindex == d3.max(filtered, function(d) { return d.values.pindex; })
```

but I'm still getting a bit lost. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Creating a minimal fiddle is always a help. Should the function inside d3.max be `function(d,i) {return d.values[i].pindex;}` since values is an array?

Comment: You could also work with the raw data itself (`cities`) instead of the D3-wrapped objects.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes I tried using:  '.attr("visibility", function(d) {               
       if (d.pindex == d3.max(filtered, function(d,i) {return d.values[i].pindex;})) <code>{return "visible"}
                    else    { return "hidden" }
                ;}) '

Comment: I get this message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Somewhat tangential, but I would suggest, rather than creating a whole new set of circle elements for these special values, you simply change the class/style of the initial circles themselves based on the data.

Comment: I would suggest again for you to create a fiddle. I find it hard to figure out what is happening. Others who are more experienced may be able to catch what is going on. If for some reason you don't want to create the fiddle, I would suggest you log key pieces of your code, e.g. what is is that you are really getting in `d.values[i].pindex`. Logging is your friend...it eliminates those darn assumptions we make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you probably want to filter your *data* rather than DOM elements. So instead of using `city.filter` you might use `cities.filter` to get the data array you're interested in. More importantly, you probably want to filter the data passed to the new `circle` selection, rather than creating all circles and then selectively showing or hiding them. I might try:

```
filtered           
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(function(d){
        var points = d.values;
        // create the array of desired points, starting with the easy ones
        var circleData = [
            // first
            points[0],
            // last
            points[points.length - 1]
        ];
        // now find min and max
        function getValue(d) { return d.pindex; }
        // d3.max returns the max value, *not* the object that contains it
        var maxVal = d3.max(points, getValue);
        // Note that you might have multiple points with the max. If you
        // don't want them all, just take maxPoints[0]
        var maxPoints = points.filter(function(d) { return d.pindex === maxVal; });
        // same for min
        var minVal = d3.min(points, getValue);
        var minPoints = points.filter(function(d) { return d.pindex === minVal; });
        // stick them all together
        return circleData.concat(maxPoints).concat(minPoints);
    })
    .enter().append('circle')
    // etc
```

Key points:

- Filter your data, not your DOM. It's less expensive processing, easier to debug, and generally much easier to get your head around.
- `d3.min` and `d3.max` don't return the object with the max value, they return the value itself, hence your `TypeError`.

Comment: thanks a million! It works (bar a minor edit for the functions to find maxPoints & minPoints)! I get what you're saying regarding filtering the data and not the DOM. Thanks for the reminder it clears things up a lot.